# Massachusetts company, working out of state

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, massachusetts

If I live in a state with no state income tax and work remotely (from home) for a company that is based in Massachusetts, do I owe any state income tax to Massachusetts? This is confusing me https://www.mass.gov/service-details/who-must-file-a-state-personal-income-tax-return

Comment: Are you a W2 employee, or 1099?

Comment: W2 employee....

Comment: Does anyone have feedback on this?

Answer (score 1):

Consult a tax professional, I am not one, this is neither tax nor league advice.
Considering salary from a current job, a regular employee would not owe state income tax in Massachusetts in a given tax year, ***ONLY*** if they were never a resident of Massachusetts for the full tax year **AND** either:

1. They never preformed any work in Massachusetts.

**Or**

2. The work preformed in Massachusetts is "casual, isolated, and inconsequential"as determined by [Massachusetts' Ancillary Activity Test (AAT) requirements](https://www.mass.gov/service-details/learn-about-massachusetts-gross-income-for-nonresidents#trade-business-or-employment-for-nonresidents).

This means work done in Massachusetts is *only* for:

- Short amounts of time.
- Infrequently, not routine.
- Doing things like training, management planning, etc

**AND**

- These activities are *secondary* to your primary out-of-state duties.

They have examples on what is and is not considered an ancillary activity on the page above.

Additional details on Massachusetts income and nonresidents: https://www.mass.gov/service-details/learn-about-massachusetts-gross-income-for-nonresidents